# Unable to establish communication between computers - PacketTracer

Tags: networking, router

I have been doing some scribbling in Packet Tracer.

[This is my layout](http://goo.gl/fJd4qV), and I can't get the PC4 communicate with PC5. I've set up subnetting, IP's and static routing, but I can't communicate with the other side.

If anybody would be kind enough and show me how to configure the routers, I’ll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: can u give us a picture about your packet tracer topology? and post show run of your cisco devices .

Comment: @FranciscoTapia here: http://goo.gl/YKCnqZ

Comment: I see now where I made mistakes. My bad.

Comment: lets me guess, default route.

Comment: Among other things.